# Button becomes smaller when clicked in jQuery mobile (CLOSED)

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am newbie in jquery mobile. I got some code from the internet for follow/unfollow button and it works. But the problem is when I click the button, the button changes text but it becomes smaller than another button next to it. This is how it looks:

[image: This is now it looks]

```js
$(document).on('click', '.followButton', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $button = $(this);
  if ($button.hasClass('following')) {
    //$.ajax(); Do Unfollow
    alert("unfollow event");

    $button.removeClass('following');
    $button.removeClass('unfollow');
    $button.text('Follow');
  } else {
    // $.ajax(); Do Follow
    alert("follow event");

    $button.addClass('following');
    $button.text('Following');
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page">
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a data-role="button" type="button" class="btn followButton" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Follow</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a data-role="button" type="button" class="btn" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

How can I make the button remain the same size after it is clicked? Thank you.

Comment: I think we need more information here. The size is probably related to CSS, which you haven't posted here. Can you link to a working example of this issue?

Comment: I see that you change the classes on the click event can you post the CSS for .following and .unfollow?

Comment: hi Jesse, hi Culyx thank you for your answer,unfortunately i don't have css, that what i ask for, because i don't know about the right css for the button, maybe u can suggest css if u dont mind. Thank You

Comment: i tested the code with jquery-mobile 1.4.5 and jquery 2.14 and there is almost nothing wrong with it. Please provide more code. Especially what version of jquery and jquery-mobile do you use and the surrounding html code from your buttons

Comment: hi @Ridrog thank you very much, i think the problem is my jquery version, i am using jquery 1.3 and jquery 1.9 and idk why its not work, but if i change my jquery-mobile into 1.4.5 and jquery 1.9 it works 
thank you once again

Comment: Show a link to the page where everything lives.